# Ubuntu 16.04 not showing new installed applications in the dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash

does anybody know why when I install new applications they do not appear in the dash unless I log out or in some cases even restart the system? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do they show up if you press Alt+F2 and type R then Enter key? How are you instaling them (command line, gdebi, software centre)?

Comment: I am using the software center, apt and gdebi, only with software center and gdebi do not show up.

Comment: no it doesn't sorry.

Comment: I have installed kdeconnect and still does not show up in dash

Comment: Other apps that I have installed i.e. virtualbox, mysql workbench and few more did not showed up straight away in the dash until i logged out or restart the machine

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Same here. I've installed applications from apt and Synaptic, and they don't show up. They run fine from the command line and from Alt+F2. It's just the dash that isn't showing them until logout/reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in 15.10 and made it into 16.04. It's been reported and marked as Confirmed. Hope a fix is released soon.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1506744

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for quite a while, and I tried every fix possible to get applications to appear, even so far as to remove Unity and install it once again. However, I discovered that Chrome had installed an app with unicode characters in the name. On Windows, it wasn't an issue at all, however, on Ubuntu, whenever this app was synced and installed, the dash stopped working like it should. Upon removing the app from chrome://apps, my dash returned to a working state. So could it be possible that apps/profiles which use special characters might be messing with the functionality of the dash?